# Hashing / How easy is it to infer the original input if the a slight variation of the input, the hash result and the hashing algorithms are known

Tags: hash, attacks

Given that I have

1. an initial input that is publicly known (e.g. "ABCDEFGHIJ")
2. a slight variation of (1) (e.g. "BACDEFGHIJ") that is used as the input to a hashing algorithm (3)
3. an modern one-way hashing algorithm like BCrypt, Scrypt etc.
4. the result hash of (2) applied to (3). The hash is also publicly known.

How easy is to infer (2) given that (1), (3), (4) are publicly known and also that its publicly known that the difference between (1) and (2) are only minute. Say both inputs are 256 bytes long and only 2 bytes are swapped in their position.

## Edit

I try to rephrase it. Given two hash function applications and 2 input values

```
h(b) = r1
h(a) = r2

where "h" is a publicly known one-way-hash-algorithm
where "a" is the input to h and its publicly known
where "r1" is the publicly known hash result 
where "r2" can be easily calculated as "a" is known and "h" is known

where "a" is known to be very similar to "b"
```

Is there any function/process/method to infer "b"

```
f(a, h, r1, r2) = b
```

The answers I would hope for are

```
[ ] there is now way to infer b from a, h, r1, r2 as all one-way-hashes have
    enough entropy (I hope this is the right term) even if the input values 
    are almost identical
[ ] given enough hash results and enough input values which are known to be 
    slight variations of the real input values one could use these (...) and 
    these (...) attacks to calculate the initial input values
[ ] Yes there are known attack vectors under this circumstances, however it 
    will need a quantum computer of the size of a NSA cluster to break it
[ ] given that a, h, r1 and r2 are known its a matter of a few minutes to 
    infer b by using the following attach vectors (...)
```

Comment: Again, bcrypt is NOT an encryption algorithm, and neither is scrypt. They're "slow hash functions" designed to be a significant enough burden for the hardware to compute so there is little point in trying to brute-force them or use precomputed rainbow tables. They are one-way functions, i.e. their result is not reversible (you can't decrypt what wasn't encrypted in the first place). I was also hoping you'll work on clarifying your original question by [editing it](http://security.stackexchange.com/posts/58159/edit), posting new ones that are just as unclear isn't helping you get good answers.

Comment: so you say its impossible to guess/compute the an input even thou I know its hash and I have another input that is almost the same?

Comment: btw I am certainly using the wrong terminology - however I guess it might be more or less obvious from my question that I am using encryption and hashing interchangeably ;-)

Comment: Actually, @TildalWave has a very valid point. If you start thinking of encryption and hashing as the same thing, you'll get into a lot of trouble one day. Webapps are awfully hard to write when the client is hashing their data instead of encrypting it.

Comment: I tried to rephrase it - I hope its more clear now